# including header files c++ not eble to use features from header

Tags: c++, header

I have one file called KONTEKST.H and other one KONTEKST.CPP.I get an error saying that "zavrsio" is not part of PCB when it actualy is.Can someone tell me why is this happening i cant find any logical explenation but i am new to c++ so what do i know :)

Error is "zavrsio is not part of PCB in function getNextPCBToExecute()"

Kontekst.h

```
#ifndef _KONTEKST_H_
#define _KONTEKST_H_

#include <iostream.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include "schedule.h"

// Zabranjuje prekide
#define lock asm cli

// Dozvoljava prekide
#define unlock asm sti



typedef void interrupt (*pInterrupt)(...);

volatile unsigned int lockFlag = 1;
volatile PCB* running;

// Zabrana ispisa
#define lockCout lockFlag =0;
// Dozvola ispisa
#define unlockCout lockFlag=1;\
if (zahtevana_promena_konteksta) {\
dispatch();\
}

void getNextPCBToExecute();

//pomocne promenljive za prekid tajmera
unsigned tsp;
unsigned tss;

volatile int brojac = 20;
volatile int zahtevana_promena_konteksta = 0;
unsigned tbp;

void interrupt timer(...);

//pokazivac na prekidnu rutinu tajmera
pInterrupt oldTimer;

// postavlja novu prekidnu rutinu
void inic();

// vraca staru prekidnu rutinu
void restore();
```

Kontekst.cpp

```
#include "kontekst.h"

void getNextPCBToExecute(){


    if(!running->zavrsio) Scheduler::put((PCB *) running);
    running=Scheduler::get();
}



void interrupt timer(...){  // prekidna rutina

    if (!zahtevana_promena_konteksta) brojac--;
    if (brojac == 0 || zahtevana_promena_konteksta) {
        if(lockFlag){
        zahtevana_promena_konteksta = 0;
        asm {
            // cuva sp
            mov tsp, sp
            mov tss, ss
            mov tbp, bp
        }

        running->sp = tsp;
        running->ss = tss;
        running->bp = tbp;

        getNextPCBToExecute();  // Scheduler

        tsp = running->sp;
        tss = running->ss;
        tbp = running->bp;

        brojac = running->kvant;

        asm {
            mov sp, tsp   // restore sp
            mov ss, tss
            mov bp, tbp
        }
    }
        else{
            zahtevana_promena_konteksta = 1;
        }
    }

    // poziv stare prekidne rutine koja se
     // nalazila na 08h, a sad je na 60h
     // poziva se samo kada nije zahtevana promena
     // konteksta – tako se da se stara
     // rutina poziva samo kada je stvarno doslo do prekida
    if(!zahtevana_promena_konteksta) asm int 60h;

}



// postavlja novu prekidnu rutinu
void inic(){
    #ifndef BCC_BLOCK_IGNORE
    oldTimer = getvect(0x08);
    setvect(0x08,timer);
    setvect(0x60,oldTimer);
    #endif
}


// vraca staru prekidnu rutinu
void restore(){
    #ifndef BCC_BLOCK_IGNORE
    setvect(0x08,oldTimer);
    #endif
}
```

PCB STRTUCTURE

```
class PCB{
public:
    unsigned sp;
    unsigned ss;
    unsigned bp;
    unsigned zavrsio;
    unsigned* stack;
    Time kvant;
    ID id;
    StackSize stackVelicina;

};
```

Comment: You need to include header file containing `PCB` definition into all the files that make use of it.

Comment: I didnt mention that i did